# Array to data Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am using "SwiftChart" library. Im uploading x and y axis to the chart.

1.) I do not know how to upload the values properly to the array

```
self.chartArray.insert(grChartStruct(x: xFloat, y: bearishFloatY), at: 0)
```

2.) I neeed to tranform that array to data (as shown below)

```
series = ChartSeries(data: chartArray[indexPath])
```

I do not want to upload these like this because im going to have to change the data

```
let data = [(x: 0.0, y: 0)
```

My code which needs fixing.

```
struct grChartStruct {
        let x : Float
        let y : Float

    }

       var chartArray = [grChartStruct]()


            let bearishFloat = 1.1
            let bullishFloat = 0.0
            var xFloat = 0.0

            self.chartArray.insert(grChartStruct(x: xFloat, y: bearishFloatY), at: 0)

         series = ChartSeries(data: chartArray[indexPath])
```

The class(library) im using

```
open class ChartSeries {
    open var data: Array<(x: Float, y: Float)>
    open var area: Bool = false
    open var line: Bool = true
    open var color: UIColor = ChartColors.blueColor() {
        didSet {
            colors = (above: color, below: color, 0)
        }
    }
    open var colors: (above: UIColor, below: UIColor, zeroLevel: Float) = (above: ChartColors.blueColor(), below: ChartColors.redColor(), 0)

    public init(_ data: Array<Float>) {
        self.data = []

        data.enumerated().forEach { (x, y) in
            let point: (x: Float, y: Float) = (x: Float(x), y: y)
            self.data.append(point)
        }
    }

    public init(data: Array<(x: Float, y: Float)>) {
        self.data = data
    }

    public init(data: Array<(x: Double, y: Double)>) {
        self.data = data.map ({ (Float($0.x), Float($0.y))})
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like you may not get many responses because the wording of your question is unclear.  What data are you trying to organize in what way.  I interpreted that you are trying to orrganize some data (still not sure what) as an array of `grCharStruct`.  Also, it would help if you only include the necessary code.  What is `ref`?

Comment: I have fixed the code. All I am trying to do is load information from firebase data base into an array. The array has to have to float values x and y

Comment: also just added part of the code im using for library

Comment: @GabeSpound I have been way more specific in my code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of data that `ChartSeries` is expecting is an array of tuples where each tuple is two `Float`s. So, in this case, you don't need a `grChartStruct` type. This should compile:

```
   var chartArray = [(x: Float, y: Float)]()

        let bearishFloat = 1.1
        let bullishFloat = 0.0
        var xFloat = 0.0

        chartArray.append((xFloat, bearishFloatY))

     series = ChartSeries(data: chartArray)
```

However, I'm concerned by the reference to `indexPath` in the last line of your code snippet. Are you displaying a number of different charts in a `UITableView`?